# 2D keypoints/features identification using HRNET32 and top down heatmap on mmpose platform

Tags: keypoint

I am using mmpose from openmmlab platform for 2D features/keypoints detection. I am using my custom dataset that has the image of satellite and I need to find keypoints in the satellite structure. I have converted my annotations in the coco format and replaced the existing coco 17 keypoints annotations with my 13 keypoints annotations. I am using hrnet-32 architecture with top down heatmap. But when I run the code then I am getting the following error. Any help would be appreciated. I would be thankful.
[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9NdC.png)

I think problem occurs in transformation during preprocessing. I have tried to avoid using transformation but even after that getting almost similar error